# Error on Magmi after move to another server

Tags: magento, magmi

I just moved to another server and cannot reindex with Magmi, I receive the error below:

This script cannot be run from Browser. This is the shell script.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when you run Magmi from the browser, because Magmi runs the indexer using `shell_exec` command, and the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` doesn't get unset.

You can try one of two things.

**Method 1.** Unset the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` variable Magento uses to check if the shell file is being run from the browser.

To do this, open `magmi/plugins/base/general/reindex/magmi_reindexing_plugin.php`

Find:

```
    public function updateIndexes()
    {
```

At the top of the `updateIndexes()` function, add the following:

```
    if(isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']))
    {
        unset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);  
    }
```

So it will look like this:

```
    public function updateIndexes()
    {
        if(isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']))
        {
            unset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);  
        }
```

---

**Method 2:** Modify the `_validate()` function in  `[magento_root]/shell/abstract.php`

Open `[magento_root]/shell/abstract.php`

Find:

```
    protected function _validate()
    {
        if (isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])) {
            die('This script cannot be run from Browser. This is the shell script.');
        }
    }
```

Replace with:

```
    protected function _validate()
    {
        if (isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])) {
            //die('This script cannot be run from Browser. This is the shell script.');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you but didn't help, I copy a part of the code below. Then I was receiving error on line 111.

 public function getIndexList()
 {
  return $this->_indexlist;
 }
 
     public function updateIndexes()
    {
        if(isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']))
        {
            unset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);  
        }
 {
  //make sure we are not in session
  if(session_id()!=="")
  {
   session_write_close();
  }
  $cl=$this->getParam("REINDEX:phpcli")." shell/indexer.php";
  $idxlstr=$this->getParam("REINDEX:indexes","");
  $idxlist=explode(",",$idxlstr);
  if(count($idxlist)==0)

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PUBLIC in /home/public_html/magmi/plugins/base/general/reindex/magmi_reindexing_plugin.php on line 111. This error I receive it in magmi.php page at the profile section.

Comment: You didn't insert the code correctly.  Make sure you are inserting it correctly and follow my instructions.  I just copy/pasted the snippet and inserted it exactly where I said and I receive no error.

Comment: OK, thanks. Now I don't receive this error but reindex is actually not running. After I moved server and see it was not working I contacted my hosting and they told me to use  /usr/bin/php5-cli instead of php, I don't know if this is related to something but I checked with both and reindex is not running after updating stock with Magmi. Any idea? Thanks again.

Comment: What are you seeing in the log output when the index is running within Magmi?

Comment: Hi Alex, please see below:
Magmi Magento Reindexer v1.0.2 - Cleaning flat tables before reindex...
Magmi Magento Reindexer v1.0.2 - running indexer
Magmi Magento Reindexer v1.0.2 - Reindexing cataloginventory_stock....
Magmi Magento Reindexer v1.0.2 -
Magmi Magento Reindexer v1.0.2 - done in 0.12 secs
Magmi Magento Reindexer v1.0.2 - Reindexing catalogsearch_fulltext....
Magmi Magento Reindexer v1.0.2 -
Magmi Magento Reindexer v1.0.2 - done in 0.12 secs

But actually the reindex didn't run.

Comment: Login to your server using shell, and `cd` to the `/shell` directory in your Magento root folder.  Once there, run the following command: `php indexer.php reindexall` and see if it re-indexes everything.

Comment: OK, good point, this is the output:

Could not open input file: indexer.php

What can be the problem? Probably permissions?

Comment: Make sure the permissions for the file are 755 for folders, 644 for files.  `cd` to your Magento root and run the following command to set the correct permissions: `chmod -R 755 *; find -type f -print0|xargs -0 chmod 644`

Comment: My hosting ran the following but still the same:
find ./ -type f -exec chmod 0644 {} \;
find ./ -type d -exec chmod 0755 {} \;

Comment: Hi,  I received this solution from hosting I can run reindex from ssh now:
The indexer.php script is located in the 'shell' folder of your Magento root if I am not mistaken. Therefore, I believe your syntax should be as follows.

> php ./shell/indexer.php reindexall

What should I modify in magmi? Thank you.

Comment: The shell command isn't related to Magmi.  You need to run it from the shell command line.  If it doesn't work from there, it's not a Magmi related issue, but an issue with your Magento setup.  I suggest hiring a Magento expert to look into it further as your issue is beyond the scope of what we can do on StackOverflow.